# Using the SuiteCRM/SugarCRM REST endpoint version 4.1

Tags: php, python, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm having a bad time trying to get the REST API to behave.  Yes, the code is Python, but if you know PHP or anything else, I suspect you'll be able to help.

I wrote two functions.  1 is a helper.

```
def post(self, method, parameters):
    args = collections.OrderedDict()
    args['method'] = method
    args['input_type'] = 'json'
    args['response_type'] = 'json'
    args['rest_data'] = json.dumps(parameters)
    res = requests.post(self.url, data=args, verify=False)
    if res.ok == False:
        return None
    return res.json()
```

In the implementation below of get_module_entries, I only ever get the first 20 records.  No matter what I set skip or take to, I only get the first 20 records.

```
def get_module_entries(self, module, skip=0, take=1):
    args = collections.OrderedDict()
    args['session'] = self.session_id
    args['module_name'] = module
    args['query'] = ''
    args['order_by'] = ''

    args['select_fields'] = ''
    args['link_name_to_fields_array'] = ''

    args['offset'] = str(skip)
    args['max_results'] = str(take)
    args['deleted'] = 0
    args['Favorites'] = 0
    res = self.post('get_entry_list', args)
    return res
```

When I comment out `select_fields` and `link_name_to_fields_array`, it does honor skip and take.  So, I can keep hitting the fuction to get all the records.  However, the objects returned only have the id and are missing all the other fields. They look like this:

`{"module_name": "Accounts", "name_value_list": [], "id": "<snipped out>"}`

Here I am commenting out those two lines.

```
def get_module_entries(self, module, skip=0, take=1):
    args = collections.OrderedDict()
    args['session'] = self.session_id
    args['module_name'] = module
    args['query'] = ''
    args['order_by'] = ''

    #args['select_fields'] = ''
    #args['link_name_to_fields_array'] = ''

    args['offset'] = str(skip)
    args['max_results'] = str(take)
    args['deleted'] = 0
    args['Favorites'] = 0
    res = self.post('get_entry_list', args)
    return res
```

The behavior is very strange.  I just want all the fields and I want it to honor skip and take.  It doesn't behave if I comment out one line and not the other in either order.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for limit by 20 results is because it is limit on the list view of SuiteCRM and the list view is paginated for performance concerns.

Typically, you would want to paginate. you really should only pull through the fields you need, as this reduces the bandwidth required to pull the data across. The result back from this call contains a next_offset key to help to request the next 20 rows. **However, you can set the limit and the offset to -1 in order to get all the beans based on your query.**

The implementation of 'get_entry_list' is in service/core/SugarWebServiceImpl.php:162. It utilises the process_list_query method which is found in data/SugarBean.php:3482. It is used by all modules of SuiteCRM to get a list of SugarBeans (models).

`process_list_query($query, $row_offset, $limit = -1, $max_per_page = -1, $where = ''`)

in service/core/SugarWebServiceImpl.php:201 there is a check which determines the offset = 0 when you passing in -1

Comment: Is there a way to do something in between 20 and "everything" without messing with that GUI setting?

Comment: Not that I am aware off. The idea is that you set the number of records per page and then request the offset for each page. Eg 20 / page. the offsets is where the range starts from eg would be 1, 21, 41 (it might be 0 20 40 i can't remember of by heart). Also the rest/soap does not effect the GUI inside of SuiteCRM. The total records are return during each call.